# Is $\sum_{n \neq 0}\left(\frac{1+∣a∣}{1+|a-n|}\right)^{100}e^{-n^2}$ bounded independently of $a$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Fix an $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the sum $$\sum_{n \neq 0}\left(\frac{1+∣a∣}{1+|a-n|}\right)^{100}e^{-n^2}.$$ Is this sum bounded independent of $a$?

I think the answer should be yes since for $n$ far from $a$, the terms in the sum are exponentially small. For $n$ close to $a$, the fraction in each term should be close to 1. Is there a way to make this rigorous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. By writing
$$
|a|\le|a-n|+|n|
$$ one has
$$
\frac{1+|a|}{1+|a-n|}\le\frac{1+|a-n|+|n|}{1+|a-n|}\le 1+|n|
$$ then
$$
\sum_{n \neq 0}\left(\frac{1+∣a∣}{1+|a-n|}\right)^{100}e^{-n^2}\le \underbrace{\sum_{n \neq 0}\left(1+|n|\right)^{100}e^{-n^2}<\infty}_{\text{independent of }a}.
$$

Comment: @Did thank you for the typo edited.

Comment: You are welcome. Neat argument, +1.